# Getting PDF object based on its location using itext

Tags: c#, itext

I am implementing a web service that can modify the content of PDF files and I am having trouble locating specific PDF elements (e.g. a text, an image etc.). Right now I am able to get the location of any elements (using coordinates like the left and top values indicating the location). So if I want to change the content of the text I can put a white box on top of the original text and add the new text on top of the box, which seems to be a stupid way to do that.

I checked this post (https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/stamping-content-existing-pdfs-itext5/replacing-pdf-objects) which stores texts as keys in a dictionary. The problem with this is that if there are several texts with same content, all of them will be changed.

Also there is another post (https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-use-text-extraction-strategy-after-applying-location-extraction-strategy) that can extract content based on locations. That is something close to what I want. My question is, given a location of a text, am I able to locate it and change the content of that text object?

Comment: You are aware that in many PDFs fonts are embedded as subsets containing only the glyphs of the original font which are used on the page in question? This means that the replacement you chose may only contain a very limited set of glyphs. (I'm a bit taken aback seeing that the first example you link to still is online; it should be an example how *not* to implement a replacement...)

Comment: *"So if I want to change the content of the text I can put a white box on top of the original text and add the new text on top of the box, which seems to be a stupid way to do that."* - it is not that stupid. If you combine this with redacting away the original text, you get the best you can sensibly do.